# Chefspec: override attribute doesn't work

Tags: rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

I'm trying to check my spec test with `bundle exec rspec` for the following test

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'my_recipe::default' do
  windows_platforms = {
    windows: %w(2008R2 2012 2012R2 2016 2019)
  }

  windows_platforms.each do |platform, versions|
    versions.each do |version|
      context "When all attributes are default, on #{platform} #{version}" do
        let(:chef_run) do
          runner = ChefSpec::ServerRunner.new(platform: platform.to_s, version: version) do |node|
            node.override['domain'] = 'mydomain.com'
          end
          runner.converge(described_recipe)
        end

        it 'converges successfully' do
          expect { chef_run }.to_not raise_error
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here's example of my default attribute file:

```
default['wsus'] =
  case node['domain']
  when 'mydomain.com'
    "do something"
  else
    raise 'Domain cannot be determined.'
  end
```

From what I understand 'mydomain.com' should be assigned as default['domain'] but seems like this isn't the case.

Here's the error I get:

```
expected no Exception, got #<RuntimeError: Domain cannot be determined.> with backtrace:
```

Does anyone have suggestion why the test won't take the overridden attribute?

p.s. If I'm not making sense, please excuse me. This is my first post on stackoverflow :(

Answer (score 1):

Your code is well, and it should be working as expected with many other attributes, but not `domain`. Point is - `domain` is *special* - it is automatic attribute set by Ohai (or in test case by Fauxhai) and it has maximum priority, which cannot be overwritten by `override` attribute. To mock automatic attributes you need `automatic` key.

```
runner = ChefSpec::ServerRunner.new(platform: platform.to_s, version: version) do |node|
  node.automatic['domain'] = 'mydomain.com'
end
```

The whole list of automatic attributes is available in [Chef docs on Ohai](https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html).